# Query to view data on Basis of Range values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have A Table in SQL name sale count

| Nodeid | OfficeName | Sales |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Delhi | 20 |
| 2 | Mumbai | 3 |
| 3 | Lucknow | 45 |
| 4 | Kolkata | 0 |
| 5 | Dehradun | 10 |
| 6 | Pune | 30 |

Need Help in writing such Query which will Produce result as below mentioned

| Sale Range | Office Count |
| --- | --- |
| 0 to 10 | 3 |
| 11 to 20 | 1 |
| 21 to 50 | 2 |

Thanks in Advance

Comment: mistakenly   added , tag removed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `case` expression.  I might suggest using `join` for this:

```
select v.sales_range, count(s.sales)
from (values (0, 10, '0 to 10'),
             (11, 20, '11 to 20'),
             (21, 50, '21 to 50')
     ) v(lo, hi, sales_range) left join
     sales s
     on s.sales >= v.lo and s.sales <= v.hi
group by v.sales_range
order by min(v.lo);
```